# Drag component within a JPanel using Gridbag layout manager

Tags: java, swing, drag, gridbaglayout

I am trying to implement dragging of a J component within a JPanel. The JPanel has to use Gridbag layout manager. 
I reviewed many dragging codes, including [Moving Windows](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/14/moving-windows/). They all use  `component.setLocation(x, y);` which has no effect when using Gridbag layout manager. 
I need help with alternative approach.

Comment: You'll need to dynamically change Gridbag's weights in response to mouse dragging.

Comment: The GridBagLayout uses constraints to control the cell in which a component is displayed. You can't just drag a component to another cell, because there will already be a component in the cell. Dragging is meant to be used with a null layout, which is why other code you have seen uses the setLocation(...) method.

Comment: You'll need to make some serious calculations to determine the layout constraints required to add the component where you want, as well as possibly change the constraints of the components around it, in order to generate the displacement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the JComponent is the only component in the JPanel, the task is not that complicated. Here is a small demo program that does it (with a bonus of re-sizing the component in response to mouse wheel events) :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class GridbagDragDemo extends JPanel {

    /**
     * Pixel width and height of positioned component.
     */
    private float  width, height;

    /**
     * Layout manger for this.
     */
    private GridBagLayout gbl;

    /**
     * Layout horizontal weights for left and right gap, and component.
     */
    private float leftWeight,xCompWeight, rightWeight;

    /**
     * Layout vertical weights for top and right gap, and component.
     */
    private float topWeight,yCompWeight, bottomWeight;

    /**
     * Min and max weight values.
     * These values can be changed to change the sensitivity of dragging.
     * For better responsiveness W_MAX can be changed in respect to the JPanl's size.
     * (also a different W_MAX can be set to horizontal and vertical axis.
     */
    private float W_MIN = 0, W_MAX = 2;

    /**
     * Keep sum an even number for calculating (int) W_SUM/2
     */
    private float W_SUM = W_MIN + W_MAX;

    /**
     * Represents the change in ratio between left / right weights
     * and top/bottom weights for every pixel of mouse drag.
     * The higher the factor the faster / more sensitive the
     * component move is.
     * Try different values to get the responsiveness you need.
     */
    private float WEIGHT_DELTA = 0.01f;

    /**
     * Represents the change (in pixels) in component width and height
     * and top/bottom weights for every mouse wheel notch.
     * The higher the factor the faster / more sensitive the
     * component resize.
     * Try different values to get the responsiveness you need.
     */
    private static final int ZOOM_FACTOR = 4;

    /**
     * Store mouse pressed position.
     */
    private float pX, pY;

    /**
     * The dragged component
     */
    private JComponent component;

    public GridbagDragDemo() {

        //set initial position to center
        leftWeight = W_SUM/2 ; xCompWeight = 0;  rightWeight = W_SUM/2;
        topWeight = W_SUM/2 ; yCompWeight = 0;  bottomWeight = W_SUM/2;

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));

        gbl = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl.columnWidths = new int[] {0, 0, 0};
        gbl.rowHeights = new int[] {0, 0, 0};
        gbl.columnWeights = new double[]{leftWeight , xCompWeight, rightWeight };
        gbl.rowWeights = new double[]{topWeight,yCompWeight, bottomWeight};
        setLayout(gbl);
        setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

        component = new JPanel();
        component.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(75,75));
        component.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(15,15));
        component.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(225,225));
        component.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        component.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black, 3));

        //add drag listeners
        component.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter(){
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {

                int mouseX = me.getXOnScreen();
                int mouseY = me.getYOnScreen();

                float moveX  =  mouseX - pX;
                float moveY  =  mouseY - pY;

                pX = mouseX;
                pY = mouseY;

                moveComp(moveX , moveY);

            }
        });
        component.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {

                //store pressed position
                pX = me.getXOnScreen();
                pY = me.getYOnScreen();
            }
        });

        //add resize listener
        component.addMouseWheelListener(new MouseWheelListener() {

            @Override
            public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent me) {

                //change sign so rolling "up" will be positive
                reSizeComp(- me.getWheelRotation());
            }
        });

        GridBagConstraints gbc_panel = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_panel.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_panel.gridx = 1;
        gbc_panel.gridy = 1;
        add(component, gbc_panel);

        width  = component.getPreferredSize().width;
        height = component.getPreferredSize().height;
    }

    private void moveComp(float moveX, float moveY) {

        if(Math.abs(moveX)>0) {

            leftWeight += WEIGHT_DELTA * moveX;
            leftWeight = (float) setValueInRange(leftWeight,  W_MIN, W_MAX);
            rightWeight = W_SUM - leftWeight;
        }

        if(Math.abs(moveY)>0) {

            topWeight += WEIGHT_DELTA * moveY;
            topWeight = (float) setValueInRange(topWeight, W_MIN, W_MAX );
            bottomWeight = W_SUM - topWeight;
        }

        gbl.columnWeights = new double[]{leftWeight,xCompWeight, rightWeight};
        gbl.rowWeights    = new double[]{topWeight, yCompWeight, bottomWeight};

        refresh();
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    private void refresh() {

        revalidate();
        getParent().repaint();
    }

    private void reSizeComp(int notches) {

        width += notches*ZOOM_FACTOR  ; height += notches *ZOOM_FACTOR  ;

        //respect min / max component size
        width  = (float) setValueInRange(width, component.getMinimumSize().getWidth(),
                                                    component.getMaximumSize().getWidth() );
        height = (float) setValueInRange(height, component.getMinimumSize().getHeight(),
                                                    component.getMaximumSize().getHeight() );
        component.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int)width,(int)height));

        refresh();
    }

    private double setValueInRange(double value, double min, double max) {

        value = (value < min ) ? min : value;
        value = (value > max ) ? max : value;

        return value;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test Gridbag drag");  
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
                frame.add(new GridbagDragDemo());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

If the JPanel holds multiple components, it becomes a totally different ball game. With multiple components the functionality is similar to what you get using  GUI builders like Eclipse' IDE [Windowbuilder](https://eclipse.org/windowbuilder/), where you can interactively move components.

Comment: Thanks for all responses and answer. I have a clearer picture now of what's involved, and a good simple solution for dragging within a panel using Gridbag layout, if no other components present.