# dragable JPanel keeps jumping back to center when edited

Tags: java, swing, layout

I have a JPanel with a textfield (textPanel). I added the textPanel for some reasons to another panel (contentPanel) and that to the JFrame. I have added a MouseListener to the textPanel, so that I can drag it around. The new Position is set by the methodcall setLocation (...)
Everytime I start editing the textfield, the textpanel jumps back from its actual location to the center of the JFrame. – Why? What do I have to change?

```
public void run() {       
    area1 = new JTextArea();
    area1.setText("Hello!");

    GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
    GridBagConstraints cc = new GridBagConstraints();
    cc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;       
    textPanel = new JPanel(layout);

    cc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
    cc.gridx = 0;   
    textPanel.add(area1, cc);

    JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    cc = new GridBagConstraints();
    cc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
    cc.gridx = 0; 
    cc.gridy = 0;
    cc.weightx = 1;
    cc.weighty = 1;

    MyMouseAdapter mh = new MyMouseAdapter();    
    textPanel.addMouseListener(mh);
    textPanel.addMouseMotionListener(mh);

    contentPanel.add(textPanel, cc);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.add(contentPanel);
    frame.setSize(800, 600);

    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: The snap back is caused by the layout manager. If you want to make the drag permanent, you should add your textpanel in the modal or popup layer of JFrame’s JLayeredPane. You also need to work out how to set its initial size & location

Comment: If you want to drag a component within a container that uses `GridBagLayout` see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35841825/3992939)

Comment: @ControlAltDel: Can you show me how? My attempts dont work ...

c0der: Thx, but he JFrame doesnt have a GridBagLayout.

Comment: The linked example is for a `JPanel` using a `GridBagLayout`, just as you do.

Comment: The job of a layout manager is to set the size/location of a component. If you want the ability to drag a component randomly, then you need to use a null layout.